# How to add increased number on every output

Tags: python

First, here is my code that I have.

```py
s = api.get_info(1230)
my_file=open('textlist.txt','r')
file_lines=my_file.readlines()
my_file.close()
###############
for line in file_lines:
    try:
        print("[+] Trying to post "+line)
        if line != '\n':
           api.update(line, post_id = s.id)
        else:
            pass
    except api.msgError as e:
        print(e.msg)
        #set interval per replies
    print("[+] Success +1...")
    sleep(10)
###############
```

And the `textlist.txt` file is

```
line_1
line_2
line_3
...
line_10
```

Output

```
[+] Trying to post line_1
[+] Success +1...
[+] Trying to post line_2
[+] Success +1...
...
```

And now **how can I make the output for** `[+] Success +1` ** to be increased every time it successfully posts the line**, like this

```
[+] Trying to post line_1
[+] Success +1...
[+] Trying to post line_2
[+] Success +2...
...
[+] Trying to post line_10
[+] Success +10...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers fail to address when updating fails. You should create a variable for the number of successes that only increments if the update succeeded.

Also consider using a `with`-statement to open your file. It will ensure the file is closed if there is an exception while it's open and is considered good practice.

```py
s = api.get_info(1230)
with open('textlist.txt','r') as my_file
    file_lines=my_file.readlines()
###############
n_successes = 0
for line in file_lines:
    try:
        print("[+] Trying to post "+line)
        if line != '\n':
           api.update(line, post_id = s.id)
           n_successes += 1 # Increment it here
           print(f"[+] Success {n_successes}...")
        else:
            pass
    except api.msgError as e:
        print(e.msg)
        #set interval per replies
    sleep(10)
print(f"Total number of successes: {n_successes}")
###############
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```py
for n_success , line in enumerate(file_lines, 1):
    try:
        print("[+] Trying to post "+line)
        if line != '\n':
           api.update(line, post_id = s.id)
        else:
            pass
    except api.msgError as e:
        print(e.msg)
        #set interval per replies
    print(f"[+] Success +{n_success}...")
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: Won't this increase `n_success` even if an exception is raised? Which I would take to mean it *wasn't* successful.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid I assume that the OP will handle the error and be able to post successfully as in his post print is outside the try except block.

Answer (score 0):

You have a delimiter in each line use that to your advantage.

Instead of:

```
print("[+] Success +1...")
```

Use:

```
print(f"[+] Success +{line.split('-')[1]}...")
```

Or:

```
print("[+] Success +{}...".format(line.split('-')[1]))
```

Comment: Just like the other answer, it doesn't take into account if the update fails. Which would mean it wasn't successful.